# Run Spring Boot Application in Test Folder using Gradle Spring Boot Plugin

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle

I've got a simple Spring Boot application. When I run `gradle bootRun` it runs the application (presumably finds the main class and runs it). I also know how to configure the `bootRun` task with an explicit `mainClass`:

```kotlin
tasks.getByName<BootRun>("bootRun") {
    mainClass.set("com.example.demo.Application")
}
```

Now, one more simple extra requirement; how can I run a Spring Boot application for which the main class is in the test folder? The best that I could come up with is:

```kotlin
tasks.getByName<BootRun>("bootRun") {
    mainClass.set("com.example.demo.test.UnderTest")
    doFirst {
        classpath += java.sourceSets["test"].runtimeClasspath
    }
}
```

But it doesn't feel right to me. What is the correct way to add the `test` source sets stuff to the classpath?
I also tried to copy the implementation of `bootRun` (in `org.springframework.boot.gradle.plugin.JavaPluginAction#configureBootRunTask`) but couldn't get it working.

A bit more context: The Spring Boot application in `test` folder is kinda the main application but configured to be the subject of integration tests.
Please note, I'm aware of `SpringBootTest` and features of Spring Test. I'm looking for a different approach for a specific requirement: Keep the Spring application running while executing *one single* test using Gradle's continues build feature in which Spring test context caching doesn't makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by adding a new Gradle custom task:

```
task startIntegrationApp(type: JavaExec) {
  group = 'integration test'
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  mainClass.set("com.example.demo.test.UnderTest")
}
```

*If you want the integration app runs parallel with the main Spring Boot app, you must combine 2 tasks as below (Make sure the Integration app runs on a different port with the Main app):*

```
task startIntegrationApp(type: JavaExec) {
  group = 'integration test'
  classpath = sourceSets.test.runtimeClasspath
  mainClass.set("com.example.demo.test.UnderTest")
}

Process process
task startIntegrationAppParallel() {
  group = 'integration test'
  doLast {
    def builder = new ProcessBuilder("CMD", "/C", "gradlew", "startIntegrationApp")
    stubProcess = builder.start()
    stubProcess.waitFor(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) // Wait for the IntegrationApp to be ready

    println "Started UnderTest app"
  }
}
```